# 500 Internal Server Error when move from xamp to a dedicated server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

Basically I have this lines into my .htaccess of my personal computer using xamp

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Whats append? Im moving to my dedicated server using apache2 on Debian 8.4
And the server gave me the next Error. Why thats append?

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Comment: 500 errors cover basically everything, so it's difficult to help. You should check the error log as directed by the error message. It might located at `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`. Update us with that error if it doesn't give you enough clues to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like mod_rewrite is not enabled in Apache. To enable it:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Such a mistake may happen because of lack of `<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>` construction, because this module might not be installed.
So, you can add this condition, but mind that it won't solve your problem - you need the module installed to have redirects.

**Update:**

So, for now you'd better change code to:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php
  RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ /$1/$2.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Read more on [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule)

Then you need to switch the mod_rewrite module, you can read example here:
[How to install the Apache mod_rewrite module](http://dev.antoinesolutions.com/apache-server/mod_rewrite)
It's more of the system administrating sphere rather than of programming.